# Post form with a page handler after changing the value in Select input

Tags: asp.net-core, dropdown, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I am rather new to .NET 6/Razor pages. **I want to mimic the behavior of the web forms when the drop down list value was changed**. In web form, I could do `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and it would hit a specific method in the code behind. What is the best way to do this with a razor page?

Currently, I have

```
<button class="btn btn-info text-white" asp-page-handler="ResetForm"><i class="fa-solid fa-ban"></i> Clear</button>    
<select asp-for="CurrentPage" onchange="ddlCurrentPageChange()" asp-items="Model.DdlPages" ></select>
    <script>
        function ddlCurrentPageChange() {
            document.getElementById("form");
        }
    </script>
```

The issue is if I click the reset button and then change the DDL value, it posts to the handler `ResetForm`

Comment: If you want to clear a form, why post to the server? Just set the button's `type` to `reset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset. Although why anyone would need a reset button is another question entirely.

Comment: `What is the best way to do this with a razor page?`Do you want to reload the page,if you want,use form as `Jacrys` said,If not,you can try to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make your onchange the submit action, which will POST:

```csharp
<form method="post" id="test">
        <select asp-for=CurrentPage onchange="document.forms['test'].submit();" asp-items=@Model.ddlPages ></select>
</form>
```

page.cshtml.cs

```csharp
public void OnPost(string currentPage)
{
    MoveTo(currentPage);
}

public void MoveTo(string page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(page);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed incorrect data as pointed out by @jeremycaney

Comment: thank you for the answer. It does work according to my original post. However, (I had not mention this), posting form `test` loses the property binding taking place in the original form and I lose other inputs this way